# android bluetooth library - porting to jni

Tags: android, bluetooth, java-native-interface, native, porting

I am working for a project at university. My professor wants me to port his android library to use JNI. As far as I read through several website, it is stated that I shouldn't go native when I want to access bluetooth, wifi, etc. Here is one of the classes which I need to port. I think this class should stay this way instead of going native.
Anyone has any idea/advice for me?
Thanks

```
package org.morphone.sense.bluetooth;

import java.util.Set;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;


public class BluetoothSense implements BluetoothSenseInterface {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;

    public BluetoothSense(){
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
    }

    @Override
    public Set<BluetoothDevice> getBondedDevices() throws BluetoothSenseException {
        try{
            return bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BluetoothSenseException("Error while getting BondedDevices (" + e.getMessage() + ")");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getState() throws BluetoothSenseException{
        try{
            return bluetoothAdapter.getState();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BluetoothSenseException("Error while getting State (" + e.getMessage() + ")");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActive() throws BluetoothSenseException{
        try{
            if (this.getState()!= BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF && 
                this.getState()!= BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF)
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BluetoothSenseException("Error while getting isActive (" + e.getMessage() + ")");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So, your professor has a working Android library in Java, and asked you to rewrite it in C++? Except for an exercise, what are the expectations of the native version?

Comment: @AlexCohn, he wants to test if the performance of the native version will be better or worse. As from what he said, it is likely that he thinks it will reduce the the power consumption

Comment: I would suggest to take a gradual approach and start with converting some pieces of the library to C++. There are two criteria that should guide your choice of scope: **1)** the pieces that are easier to rewrite; **2)** the performance bottlenecks (use profiler to detect them).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to implement `org.morphone.sense.bluetooth.BluetoothSense` completely in C++, but it will either still use the Java `android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter` and thus  give zero performance gain if it is not used efficiently, e.g. if `bluetoothAdapter.getState()` is called more often than necessary.

Note that there may be lots of performance improvements with Java code, too. For example, the `BluetoothSense.isActive()` method will be twice as power efficient if rewritten as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean isActive() throws BluetoothSenseException {
    try {
        int state = getState();
        if (state != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF && 
            state != BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF)
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BluetoothSenseException("Error while getting isActive (" + e.getMessage() + ")");
    }
}
```

The change is not worthwhile, naturally, if `isActive()` is not called often in the app.